# Close Octave-cli instances while using Oct2Py in loop

Tags: python, octave, oct2py

So I'm running into an increasingly annoying problem while using Oct2Py in my python code to run a few Matlab codes. Every time I run Oct2py in my script it opens in my processes an octave-cli.exe *32 for each one but does not close it after the process is finished.  Since I have multiple uses of it and now wish to have a loop of about a thousand this has become a problem.

Is there some command I can give to close the octave client after the run has been performed?  I haven't found any references about this.

Something like:

```
ans = oc.read_file(filename)
close(octave)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`exit` method](https://github.com/blink1073/oct2py/blob/master/oct2py/core.py#L108) of the `Oct2Py` class will close the underlying Octave session.

```
ans = oc.read_file(filename)
oc.exit()
```

The constant spawning of Octave sessions in a loop may itself be a performance bottleneck. it may be worth writing your code such that you can reuse the `Oct2Py` instance each time through the loop.

```
octave = Oct2Py()

for filename in filenames:
    # Call Octave command
    output = octave.read_file(filename)

    # Perform any necessary cleanup
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Yeah I know I need to work on the efficiency of my code skills but if only there was enough time.  But the exit command did work, thanks.